# How do I get started on working with the Twitter API?

Tags: java, python, twitter

I'm working on a project that involves using Twitter.

I began to use Tweepy and put in the following code...

import tweepy

```
"""public_tweets = tweepy.api.public_timeline()
print "hi"
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text"""

auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler('username', 'password')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status('hello from tweepy!')
```

...But I got this error that says Tweety does not have an error module. I looked in the Tweety folder and a PY file called "error" was there... what am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karan/Desktop/untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
import tweepy
  File "C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_tweepy-master.zip\tweepy-master\tweepy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.models import Status, User, DirectMessage, Friendship, SavedSearch, SearchResults, ModelFactory, Category
  File "C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_tweepy-master.zip\tweepy-master\tweepy\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tweepy.error import TweepError
ImportError: No module named error
```

Answer (score 1):

The most popular and fully featured python module is `tweepy`, available at https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy. I'd recommend it over the similar `python-twitter` module as `tweepy` has increased functionality, including increased oauth customization and the ability to edit user profiles. To get started, read its [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/index.html).

Here's some example code:

```
# Posts a tweet from a user.
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler('username', 'password')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status('hello from tweepy!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want the twitter api? 
https://dev.twitter.com/

https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ < hope this helps.